# ¿Cómo poner esta variable de SQlite igual a 0?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Tengo el siguiente código que se puede encontrar por la red sobre una base de datos SQLite:

```
public void alta(View v) {
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"administracion", null, 1); //Creamos instancia llamada Admin
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase(); //Creamos base de datos y writable para decir que es totalmende modificable

    String dni = et1.getText().toString();
    String nombre = et2.getText().toString();
    String colegio = et3.getText().toString();
    String nromesa = et4.getText().toString();

    ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();  //Clase para guardar datos

    //LO QUE HAY ENTRE COMILLAS ES LO MISMO LLAMADA EN LA CLASE SQLITE DE JAVA,IMPORTANTE LOS NOMBRES.
    registro.put("dni", dni);
    registro.put("nombre", nombre);
    registro.put("colegio", colegio);
    registro.put("nromesa", nromesa);

    bd.insert("votantes", null, registro); //null siempre por defecto
    bd.close(); //Cerramos si no da problemas.

    et1.setText("");
    et2.setText("");
    et3.setText("");
    et4.setText("");

    Toast.makeText(this, "Se cargaron los datos de la persona",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //CARTEL TOAST PARA AVISAR A USER. 
}

public void consulta(View v) {
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,
            "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase(); //Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing.

    String dni = et1.getText().toString();//Me interesa solo dni porque es lo que voy a consultar

    Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery(  //devuelve 0 o 1 fila //es una consulta
            "select nombre,colegio,nromesa  from votantes where dni=" + dni, null);
    if (fila.moveToFirst()) {  //si ha devuelto 1 fila, vamos al primero (que es el unico)
        et2.setText(fila.getString(0));
        et3.setText(fila.getString(1));
        et4.setText(fila.getString(2));
    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No existe una persona con dicho dni" ,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    bd.close(); //Cerramos la base
}
```

Mi problema está en  `if (fila.moveToFirst())`  que se encuentra dentro de la función consulta. Esta función SENCILLAMENTE lee lo que pongo en DNI y devuelve los datos si los tiene.

Lo único que quiero saber cómo se pone es si DNI está vacío. Qué poner dentro de ese `if ( )` para que me lea si DNI está vacío.

Comment: alguna de las respuestas soluciono tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien a que te refieres, si el Dni esta vacío entonces la consulta no te devolverá ninguna fila ¿no? y te da error el trozo de código:

```
if (fila.moveToFirst()) {  //si ha devuelto 1 fila, vamos al primero (que es el unico)
        et2.setText(fila.getString(0));
        et3.setText(fila.getString(1));
        et4.setText(fila.getString(2));
    }
```

lo que puedes hacer es poner lo siguiente:

```
if (fila.moveToFirst())
    while (!fila.isAfterLast()) {
        et2.setText(fila.getString(0));
        et3.setText(fila.getString(1));
        et4.setText(fila.getString(2));
    }
}
```

De esta forma si tu consulta no devuelve filas no dará error al intentar obtener los datos correspondientes a las columnas.

Si no es esto a lo que te refieres podrías especificarme un poco más cual es el problema.

Comment: Yo tengo dos campos, DNI y NOMBRE. En el código original es el código que yo he puesto arriba. Pongo DNI y busco y si encuentra coincidencia me devuelva el nombre. Lo que yo quiero es dejar el DNI vacío y que al pinchar en consultar, al detectármelo vacío me devuelva el nombre. Es decir, que no haga falta poner ningún DNI.

Comment: Lo que yo quiero es ( con el campo de DNI vacío, siempre) guardar un nombre, pincho en "alta" y se me guarda. Después a la hora de buscarlo ( con el campo DNI vacío) pincho en consultar y me salga dicho nombre. Eso quiero.

Comment: Pero si tu consultas con el Dni vacío te saldrán todos los nombres que tengan el Dni vacío, ya que la consulta que tu has puesto te devolverá todos aquellos que cumplan esa condición a no ser que sólo vayas a tener uno con el Dni vacío cada vez. Igual lo que deberías hacer seria cambiar la consulta y consultar por nombre o por el ID (si has puesto alguno en la tabla) y luego ya cuando quieras asignarle el Dni

Comment: Y como poner entonces Joacer, que lea una determinada cadena? Es decir, que en DNI siempre y siempre lea por ejemplo el número 5667, dentro del if que debo poner? Lo que yo quiero es que lea algo siempre.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿ Qué poner dentro de ese if ( ) para que me lea si DNI está vacío?.

El mismo método [moveToFirst()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) del cursor te indica que si se movio existen datos, de otra forma el cursor esta vacío.

> [moveToFirst()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) : Este método retorna falso si el cursor esta vacío.

Por lo tanto, lo que deseas ya lo estas realizando:

```
if (fila.moveToFirst()) { 
//Encuentra datos.
} else{
//Vacio, NO encuentra datos.
}
```

Comment: Yo tengo dos campos, DNI y NOMBRE. En el código original es el código que yo he puesto arriba. Pongo DNI y busco y si encuentra coincidencia me devuelva el nombre.  Lo que yo quiero es dejar el DNI vacío y que al pinchar en consultar, al detectármelo vacío me devuelva el nombre. Es decir, que no haga falta poner ningún DNI.

Comment: Lo he intercambiado , lo de else al if y lo del if al else, y cuando guardo información y después la consulto SIEMPRE con el DNI vacío, me sale error y se me sale de la aplicación